# pages disable after wordpress update

Tags: php, updates, fatal-error

today I updated my wordpress to latest version but the update didnt complete & all the pages were throwing maintenance message so I deleted the maintenance file from the server, now I can access the index.php but still all other pages are disabled. 
I enabled the php debugging here's the error message

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Post_Type' not found in
>   /home/******/public_html/shaheer.xyz/wp-includes/post.php on line
>   1031

Please help me with this

Comment: The update process didn't complete successfully and some files appears to be corrupted, try reinstalling WP.

Comment: @OmarSoliman Its a really old website with a lot of customers, I'm afraid reinstalling is not an option for me. Is there anything else I can do about this?

Comment: Yes you can, download latest version of [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) and unzip the archive, then connect to your website FTP and upload the **wp-includes** and **wp-admin** folders, if you were asked to replace existing files, do it, also **do not mess with wp-content or the database.** and one more thing, try to do a backup first if possible.

Comment: now I'm getting the same error on every page of my website

Comment: Same error? Fatal error: Class 'WP_Post_Type' not found in /home/******/public_html/shaheer.xyz/wp-includes/post.php on line 1031 ?

Comment: yes, same error

Comment: Do you have a backup? Restore back to the latest point and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had just changed the version number in version.php back to 4.5.3 (was playing with wp-cli but don't ask why, LOL) and saw this exact error -- Googled it and saw this post.

My bet is your version.php didn't get updated. Look in it and check the version number to see if it is what it should be.